# How to design Flows to stay under new per-month governor limit?

Tags: visual-workflow, governorlimits

As I am aware, the "Maximum Flow Interviews Without UI per Month" governor limit is relatively new in a recent release of Salesforce. One of my Salesforce orgs has a few hundred Salesforce users and is hitting the 100 million invocations per month limit. (I put in a request with Salesforce support to raise that limit.)

Governor limit description: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_usage_entitlements.htm

My question is: How does Salesforce advise me to design/architect the flows & process builders in my orgs to stay under this limit? That org doesn't have a crazy number of process builders, so I feel like that governor limit is crazy low, *or* I am not creating these flows like Salesforce advises.

A secondary question: What does that limit have to do with "Flow Usage-Based Entitlements"?

Comment: I did check mine, my allowance is 20K and Amount Used is 27K. Am not sure how billing works, but its not a hard limit and you can buy more if need. Should be farily cheap